# wrong rate limit in twitter

Tags: php, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am new to twitter API started working on it on PHP using [this library](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/).

```
// connecting to it and asking for user look up
$twitter = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
$twitter->host = "https://api.twitter.com/1/";
$userInfo= $twitter->post( 'users/lookup', array('user_id' => "".$id)); // i am talking about this line
```

here I am calling users/lookup for each id I have (I know I can put multiple ids comma seprated) but I didn't know that before; any way I noticed I get the rate limit of 150 calls why can't I do more? it should 350 calls since I am using Oauth, is this correct?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of problems in your code.

1. You are using API version `1.0`. **`users/lookup` is not available in `1.0`**. Its introduced in `1.1`. Use endpoint `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/` first.
2. **`user/lookup` is a `GET` request not `POST`**. see [GET user/lookup](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/lookup). Use `$twitter->get()` method.
3. **Rate limit for `GET users/lookup` is `180` per `15` minute** window. Thats `720` per hour. See [REST API V1.1 Limits](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1/limits)

Your final code should something like this,

```
$twitter->host = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/";
$userInfo= $twitter->get( 'users/lookup', array('user_id' => "".$id));
```

Comment: thank you very much , i am currently in office , once at home i will do the changes and test,  regarding it being get i found in their doc site the following text  "You are strongly encouraged to use a POST for larger (up to 100 screen names) requests." in the following link https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/lookup thats why i used post

Answer (score 1):

@shiplu.mokadd.im [users/lookup](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/lookup) existed in v 1.0 also.

I'm having the same problem with v1, but it seems to be a [common problem](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/13097) recently.

Comment: Ifs its in v1 why its not specified in api doc?

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't seem to have a direct link on the official [twitter api v1](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1) but you will find it mentioned it there on some other methods description. Also the [direct link](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/lookup) seems to work. Perhaps they've removed it recently...